# How to deal with "File is blocked by robots" when testing universal link?

Tags: ios-universal-links

when I use https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ to test universal link

it said "failed. File is blocked by robots. Please check your url and try again."

But my robots.txt:

> User-agent: * Disallow: